# How to override the existing project component with new component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Angular project called **CustomDemoApp** Inside node modules there is a **DemoApp** which is a parent App of **CustomDemoApp**.
In the Parent App(DemoApp), I have Login page but I have to Add some extra features on top of it.

1. I tried inheriting LoginComponent to my **CustomLoginComponent**. we are reusing only logic but view are again repeating in CustomApp.

Currently I am facing a challenge of URL which should be same as **ParentLoginComponent**.

2.Example if we type ParentApp LoginComponent URL it should render our CustomLogin page.

```
CustomAPP
dist
e2e
nodeModules-->DemoApp(Budled) src-->App-->
 Component-->LoginComponent 
   
Src-->App-->Component-->CustomeLoginComponent
package.json
```

Please find below code snippet. Tried loading component by CustomLoginService

In CustomAppModule:

```
providers[
{provide:DynamicServ, useValue:CustomLoginService }
]
```

I am confused with this custom architecture that has created by some one. But they are saying we can achieve reusable code and also custom modification with the same flow.
And I didn't see any separate routing for these projects. I may be wrong please help me to overcome from this.

Comment: Demo app is probably an Angular lib and might have a demoAppModule. Should be enough to import the module.

Comment: DemoApp is a core project which is bundled. I have inaherited the Appmodule but iam not able to see customLogin page